# SMB transactions against Azure Files vs Billing transaction count

Tags: .net, f#, smb, azure-files

According to the [Azure Files Pricing Page](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-au/pricing/details/storage/files/)

*Write transactions are any operations which modify a file’s data stream. This category also includes file handle operations.*

and

*Read transactions are any operations which read from a file’s data stream*

As an experiment I mounted an Azure Fileshare to Z:\ on my Windows machine. And ran the below silly bit of code whilst sniffing the SMB transactions with Wireshark

```
let a = FileStream(@"z:\foo.txt", FileMode.Open)
let _buf = Array.zeroCreate(1)
[0..50000] |> Seq.iter (fun i ->
    let bte = a.Read(_buf, 0, 1)
    printf "%s" (Encoding.ASCII.GetString(_buf))
)
a.Close()
```

There are 7 SMB request-response pairs for the `FileStream` constructor call

In the example above 5 request-response pairs for the iteration (I assume there are only 5 because of SMB caching ?)

And 1 request-response for the `Close()`

From an Azure billing point of view how many transactions does the above constitute ?

Is it 1 (as I'm only operating on 1 file), 5 (as there are 5 SMB reads), or 13 (for each SMB action)

Comment: Licencing/billing is explicitly off-topic for [so], sorry.

Comment: Where is such a question on-topic then ?

Comment: I think you are just supposed to contact your rep.

Comment: I don't have a rep, I'm just a public azure customer. I've just read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274963/questions-about-licensing and I'm not convinced the question is off-topic. There is nothing legal in the question. I could code up 2 instances that run in different ways and run them for a month and then compare the bill to answer my own question. But I was obviously mistaken that reaching out to the community was a better idea.

Answer (score 2):

After some more testing it looks like each SMB action (as logged by Wireshark) constitutes a billable transaction.

I ran a test on a ~33mb file and changed the code to do a single read of the entire length

```
let bte = a.Read(_buf, 0, int a.Length)
```

Wireshare captured 46 SMB events. In the Azure portal, under the service metrics 46 transactions were logged.

Repeating the test. This time only reading 1 byte at a time for the full 33mb file. Wireshark logged 218 SMB events and the same was reported in the portal.

I did a further test and uploaded a ~60mb file which produced 92 wireshark logs and 92 transaction in the portal.

After reading [Understanding Azure Files Billing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/understanding-billing) and [this excellent article](https://www.vioreliftode.com/index.php/what-does-microsoft-mean-by-low-moderate-high-very-high-extremely-high-azure-network-bandwidth-part-2-3/) I discovered the logic.

Files are typically read/written by SMB in 1 mb chunks. For my ~33mb and ~60mb files where I uploaded/downloaded the full file, the number of transactions roughly corresponds to the number of 1 mb chunks in the file + the overhead transactions of opening and closing the file.

For the contrived example where 1 byte reads were performed by my code, SMB (in my tests) downloaded roughly ~160 bytes at a time from Azure Files and then buffered that to my code.

**What does all this mean for a SO audience ?**

If you are using the standard `System.IO` classes against a mounted Azure Files drive. Don't read and write in < 1 mb chunks if you want to be budget friendly.

In my case I'm developing a VFS cache over Azure Files with [Dokan dotnet](https://github.com/dokan-dev/dokan-dotnet) and I wanted to understand the cost ramifications of blindly pushing every local file delta to Azure.